# Horizontal css slider bar

Tags: css

I want to have a complete css coded horizontal slider bar. I am now sick of jquery's several version and so I decided to have a complete css silder bar.

Please post any links if anybody know any slider horizontal bar.

In the slider bar I can be able to set the min and the max position .Also when the page is loaded i can be able to set the slider handle to a some specific location between the min and the max value.

Comment: You should just figure out the jQuery slider.

Comment: any kind of css only slider bar is going to be 100% non-crossbrowser

Answer (score 1):

CSS normally cannot respond to complex user actions like dragging the mouse.

It would be really easy to use the "range" form attribute of HTML5 forms (HTML rather than CSS):
http://jsfiddle.net/UnJMu/
But this will only work in browsers that support it (probably latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari).

If you want a cross-browser solution, just use jQuery.